# Scheduling a backup in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup

I am trying to schedule back up in SQL Server 2005 with management option. I am unable to find database name while scheduling a backup with full option. Database name is not over there in selected area. What can be the reason?

Comment: Are you sure you're on the right instance?  I'm guessing you're talking about a maintenance plan?

Comment: Do you have enough privileges to backup the database?

Comment: Try out [SQLBackupAndFTP](http://sqlbackupandftp.com/) tool. You can select SQL Server instance and databases for backup. Basic features are available in free version (and scheduler too).

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187510.aspx) may help you to back up the data

Comment: I know how to take back up manutally but At time of scheduling the back up automatically, The database name is not there in list of all databases. what can be the reason?

Comment: search All files instead of .bak in the list.

Comment: Database name is not there, I am not looking for .bak file. I am schduling back up process thru which back up of database will be automatically done.